# How should I categorise/record an "account adjustment" on my current account?

Tags: united-kingdom, compensation

Santander failed to notify me of an interest rate decrease on my student current account from 3% AER to 1% AER, which I noticed a few months after the change. I submitted a complaint to them over the phone, and they called me back a few days later to say that they would compensate me by crediting my account with £25, which was more than the lost interest over the period where I was unaware of the change, so I accepted it.

The £25 credit to my current account appears on my statement as an "account adjustment". My question is: how should I classify this sort of compensatory income in my books and on my self-assessment tax return, e.g.

- interest from savings;
- tax-free gift/goodwill from the bank, similar to bank account rewards;
- miscellaneous income that is subject to Income Tax;
- something else?

Comment: "Interest from savings" seems to be what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having now received my account summary / interest statement from Santander for the tax year concerned, it is clear that the £25 they awarded me is not classed as interest for tax purposes, as it is not accounted for in that statement. I have filed it in my books as goodwill received.